# "Importing" generic type from another class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to represent a Graph with Nodes and Edges.

I have a class Node which has to be:

```
public class Node<NodeType>
```

and another class Edge, which I am allowed to parameterize in any way. At first I thought `Edge<EdgeType>`, but since they have Nodes as an atribute, I ended up doing the following (mostly because Eclipse told me about Node being a raw type if I did not parameterize it)

```
public class Edge<EdgeType, NodeType> {
    private Node<NodeType> start;
    private Node<NodeType> end;
    private EdgeType value;
    ...
}
```

This gives me the ability to work without problems in the Edge class, but there are some methods in the Node class which require working with Edges, such as

```
public List<EdgeType> edgesValues(Node<NodeType> node) {
    /*Returns a list of values of the edges between the node it is called on and the node given by argument*/
}
```

which I can't use because EdgeType is not defined. Since I cannot add another parameter in the Node class, I do not know how to "import" EdgeType into it.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what it means that "there are some methods in the Node class which require working with Edges"? Are you given some strict interfaces (maybe even unit tests)? Or is it just your *wish* to have a method like `edgesValues`? Try to separate the hard requirements (prescribed interfaces) from the functions that you currently think would be nice to have. Maybe you are just trying to implement something you are not supposed to, because your understanding of the interfaces is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is quite simple, use generic methods :

```
public <EdgeType> List<EdgeType> edgesValues(Node<NodeType> node) {

}
```

but passing a `Node<NodeType>` as parameter within a instance of `Node<NodeType>` doesnt make much sense - methinks you got yourself a design flaw right there, maybe you should use another design pattern

Comment: What is the implementation supposed to look like? What if the user calls `edgesValues<Bar>` on a node that is internally `edgesValues<Foo>`?

Comment: The implementation could look exactly like my code sample. If it is called like in your question a list of `<Bar>` is returned - but the parameter has to be of type `<Foo>`, which may or may not be compatible to `<Bar>`, of course. It wont compile otherwise. Thats the beauty of genrics, i recommend reading a tutorial on the subject.

Comment: I guess my question is not clear enough.
Suppose that you have two nodes `a`,`b` of type `Node<Zab>` which are connected by edges of type `Edge<Foo>`. Then you just take `a` and call `a.edgesValues<Bar>(b)`, where `Bar` has nothing to do with `Foo`. How is the compiler supposed to figure out that something is wrong, if there is no mention of `Foo` in the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: there is nothing to "figure out" here because theres nothing "wrong". Please do some research about generics, you obviously have got many questions. The answer above mine is a more complete, yet identical solution (and its a workaround for these generic type-junctions); it may guide you through your exercises.

Comment: What's the point in arguing about imaginary code no one has ever seen and trying to sell me some "generics exercises" in the comments? If you have a good solution: great, edit your answer, add some concrete code, explain how it is to be used, get your points.

Comment: that ... doesnt make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: I chose this answer as the one I accept since it is the only one I could apply to my code. I realize Misha's answer is better in design, but that is not the point of my specific question.

Answer (score 2):

I would put `edgesValues` method into a separate class that's parametrized by both `NodeType` and `EdgeType`:

```
class Node<N> {
    N value;
}

class Edge<E, N> {
    Node<N> from;
    Node<N> to;
    E value;
}

class Graph<E, N> {     
    Node<N> newNode(N nodeVal) {
        ...
    }

    Edge<E, N> newEdge(E edgeVal, Node<N> from, Node<N> to) {
        ...
    }

    List<E> edgesValues(Node<N> node) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: edgesValues  returns a list of values of the edges between the node it is called on and the node given by argument (edited on post), so I can't do this. I also can't do it with two node arguments since the task forces me to call the method from a node.

Comment: I feel there are some things about this task that are missing from your description.  The only way to meet all these constraints is either give up compile-time type safety or have `Node` be an inner class to a class parametrized by `EdgeType`.

Comment: Please read my comment on the answer I accepted. I apologize for not explaining better the situation. I would, however, like to thank you for the more direct answer "The only way to meet all these constraints is either give up compile-time type safety or have Node be an inner class to a class parametrized by EdgeType" which really helped on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you "have a class Node which has to be" something fixed, then you should remove the `EdgeType` from the `Edge`, you aren't using it anyway:

```
 public class Edge<N> {
    private Node<N> start; 
    private Node<N> end;
    private int value;
 }
```

In your `Node` class, you don't need any additional type parameters now:

```
 public List<Edge<N>> edges(...) { ... }
```

You probably won't need anything more complex than `int`'s anyway.

Comment: The Graph must be made in a way that both Edges and Nodes can be any type of object, my bad for not indicating it. Edit: actually I wrote NodeType instead of EdgeType on the values atribute.

Comment: complexity reduction is not always a solution. In fact, that may very well INCREASE complexity if your design pattern doesnt match the original task anymore; maybe because you reduced it ad absurdum. A skilled software engineer knows how to find the golden cut between complexity and simplicity

Comment: @specializt If the skilled software engineer is not allowed to modify the interfaces in his homework problem statement, then writing the most primitive throw-away code *is* a good solution.

Comment: @Jurcan Then you need some other class that knows what the type of the edges is: Micha has provided a good solution for this case. If all you have is just an instance of `Node<String>`, there is just no type safe way to get an `Edge<URL>` out of it, no matter what. You need something that stores the type `URL`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it is not necessary to modify the interfaces. At all. By the way : he didnt even mention such a restrication, you made that up. Another thing : students & pupils are no software engineers - and in many cases, they arent even skilled. Thats why they're still studying.

Comment: The first sentence in the question is: "I have a class Node which has to be: public class Node<NodeType>", so I did not "make it up". However, the part about "homework" is indeed just an educated guess.